# Can (Close) send a ctrl-C (Php cli.exe) to an application on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, system, exe

```
static Process procphp;
static void runPhpCommand()
    {
        string cPath = @"php";
        string cParams = "-S localhost:80";
        string filename = Path.Combine(cPath, "php.exe");
        procphp = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, cParams);
    }
```

This code Working.
How to close this Process

more code or explanations what exactly is not working

```
   procphp.CloseMainWindow();
   procphp.Close();
```

**procphp.CloseMainWindow();**

**procphp.Close();**

**Support Without parameter**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to close this Process

Comment: Just like you wrote: `procphp.CloseMainWindow();
   procphp.Close();`

Comment: procphp.CloseMainWindow();
   procphp.Close(); NOT WORKING

Comment: procphp.CloseMainWindow();
   procphp.Close(); #only support with out parameters#

Comment: What do you mean *only support with out parameters* ?

Comment: procphp.CloseMainWindow(); AND procphp.Close(); 
Work
procphp.Start(@"php\\php.exe");
try to parameters.if notworking.

Comment: I'm sorry buy I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. could you try editing you question with more code or explanations what exactly is not working?

Comment: If you run PHP in server mode, does it *have* a main window to close?  Have you tried using `.Kill()` instead?

Comment: ... a more elegant approach would be to have a script on your web site to shut down the server.  I'm not sure whether PHP provides any built-in way to do this, but you can apparently call external DLLs and such a DLL could call `raise` - although you'd have to ensure that the DLL was using the same C runtime library as PHP.

Comment: Dear all, I found out........Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("php");
        foreach (var process in processes)
        {
            process.Kill();
        }

Comment: @WarunaManjula you could have avoided trouble if you simply checked the methods of the Process class, either in the docs, intellisense, or simply placing the cursor on `Process` and hitting F1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dear all, I found out.**

```
        try
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("php");
            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(process.ToString());
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No");
        }
```